# Linking Tables through SQL and showing the row

Tags: php, sql

**Table: tpayments**
date
job_no
item
amount
id

**Table: tjobs**
job_no
job_name
value
start_date
completion_date
duration_mths
type_no
manager_no
client_no
location
status
notes

I tried using this:

> SELECT * from tpayments LEFT JOIN tjobs ON
>   tjobs.job_no=tjobs.job_no WHERE location = 'Qatar';

Sorry but, I'm currently studying linking tables through SQL.

All I want is just to display the row of payments if the location is in Qatar, based on the tjobs table.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error/unexpected output you are receiving?

Comment: It looks like you would really benefit from reading this [Q&A that I wrote for times just like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) it covers off joins of tables, selecting only specific data and a whole bunch more. Do yourself a favour and have a read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM tpayments AS p
LEFT JOIN tjobs AS j
ON p.job_no = j.job_no
WHERE j.location = 'Qatar';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is joining `tjobs` to itself. you need to join it to `tpayments`

```
 ON tjobs.job_no = tpayments.job_no
```

Comment: but, it combines the field of the 2 tables, I just need only to show the tpayments table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT t.date, t.job_no, t.item, t.amount_id from tpayments t
LEFT JOIN tjobs ts ON t.job_no=ts.job_no 
WHERE ts.location = 'Qatar';
```

Comment: SAME COMMENT AS BELOW Thanks!